# Windows signtool.exe sign command /s option

Tags: windows, sdk, wdk, signtool

When using the `signtool` to digitally sign a catalog file (*.cat), what does the `/s` option actually do?

Example:

```
signtool sign /s SomeStore c:/someCAT.cat
```

What does the `SomeStore` parameter for the `/s` option do?  How does one confirm that this parameter is correct?

I have checked the Microsoft signtool documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz(v=vs.110).aspx#sign, but it does not seem to provide this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/s` option refers to the Certificate Store from which the `signtool` will be obtaining the data (credentials) necessary to sign the catalog file.  See the following:

Digital Certificates: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381975(v=vs.85).aspx

Certificate Stores: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386971(v=vs.85).aspx

Running the `signtool` with the `verify` command provides feed back on whether the store specified with the `/s` option was valid.

Example:

```
signtool verify /pa /v c:\someCAT.cat
```

where the `/pa` and `/v` are described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764(v=vs.85).aspx